# Is asyncore recommended for writing a Python TCP server on a robot that will receive GPS coordinates from an Android Client?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, tcp

This is the general structure of my project -

Android TCP client connects to Robot (Linux + Python TCP Server). Robot waits for messages from App.

One feature on the robot requires GPS coordinates for navigation. Python Server waits for a continuous stream of messages consisting of GPS data from the Android App.

When I wish to stop the navigation, a message "Stop" is sent from the App to the robot. The robot upon receiving that message sends back a confirmation message, then waits again for further messages from the App.

Is asyncore recommended here? I was previously working with a threaded client class on the robot, but was advised to have a server on the robot instead. That threaded client class was always waiting for a message, and was blocking the socket from sending that confirmation message for some reason.

Please help me understand the basic underlying concept when it comes to server-client communication here, and how to approach it. Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Any specific suggestions? Or a way to learn why and which one is better for my case? Trying to develop an intuition here as well.

Comment: Try them out and see what's easiest/works the best. Me? I'd probably jump to using something like [0mq](http://zeromq.org/), but if you haven't done your own client/server using plain ol' TCP/IP, used HTTP with some libraries (either included or external like Flask, Bottle, CherryPy or others), or tried other approaches like asyncio, twisted, tornado, 0mq, rabbitmq, and while we're at it postgres and redis pub/sub, then you really won't have much to go on. Experience breeds intuition.